# Given a set $X$ and a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa<|X|$, can I always find a subset of $X$ which has cardinality $\kappa$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given a set $X$ and a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa<|X|$, can I always find a subset of $X$ which has cardinality $\kappa$?

If that's the case, then there must be a subset of the reals which has cardinality $\aleph_1$ ( even though we cannot prove there's a bijection between it and the reals themselves ) is there an explicit example of such a subset?

Comment: The answer may depend on your set theory. For example, without the Axiom of Choice (or at least some weaker version, such as Countable Choice), you cannot show that every infinite set contains an infinite countable subset (that is, a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$).

Comment: Do you mean $\aleph_0 $?  Because I normally think of $\aleph_1$ as the cardinality of $\Bbb R$.  Though some expert will probably say this assumes CH.  There is a different symbol,  but I've forgotten what it is.   Surely I can find it by googling.   Anyway there's $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb R$ at $\aleph_0 $, and any interval at $\aleph_1$.  I see the responders below are both at a higher level than myself, in this.  The symbol I was looking for was $\beth$.  Sorry experts, for being like a bull in a China shop.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you, that's nice how even simple constructions turn out to be independent of ZF. I was actually expecting it to be provable in it.

Comment: You are assuming that $\aleph_1 \ne 2^{\aleph_0}$?  The continuum hypothesis states it is.  If we don't accept the continuum hypotheses and assume it isn't then yes, there can be a subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$ but, like $\aleph_1$ itself, t is hypothetical.

Comment: @fleablood: Also if we *do* assume the continuum hypothesis, such subsets exist. One obvious example in that case is $\mathbb R$ itselt. But if you want a proper subset, take $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Indeed, when assuming the continuum hypothesis, we don't even need AC for that statement.

Comment: celtschk.  Well, I was taking it for granted that if we as assume CH and $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb R|$, that subsets of cardinality $\aleph_1 = |\mathbb R|$ would be would be trivial to find and well-known.  It's only if $\aleph_0 < \aleph_1 < 2^{\aleph_0}$ that the existence of such subsets come into question.  I may be wrong but I was under the impression that they must exist but can not be described (much as $\aleph_1$ itself can not be).

Comment: @ChrisCuster: It's not just experts that will tell you that assuming $|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_1$ means assuming the Continuum Hypothesis; it's anyone who actually knows what $\aleph_1$ means and what CH states. Though it is not uncommon to find a lot of people who think that what CH states is that "there isn't any cardinal strictly between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$", in fact $\aleph_1$ is **by definition**, the smallest cardinal strictly larger than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @fleablood: I read your comment as stating that only if the continuum hypothesis is wrong, there exist subsets of cardinality $\aleph_1$. On re-reading, I notice that that's not the only possible interpretation of your comment. So you were not wrong, I just misunderstood what you meant to say. BTW, if you omit the “@” in front of the user name, I don't get notified of your comment.

Comment: @celtschk... yeah, I know you don't get notified.  I didn't think it was important enough to grab you by the shirtcollars and demand that I knew what I was talking about.  I can see how it was interpreted as *only* if but.... again, obviously $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb R$ as are $(0,\infty)$  or $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ or ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the cardinality of set $Y$ is smaller than the cardinality of set $X$ exactly if there exists an injection from $Y$ into $X$. Obviously the image of $Y$ in $X$ then has the same cardinality as $Y$. Thus yes, if $k<|X|$, then $X$ has a subset of cardinality $k$.

And this indeed means that $\mathbb R$ has a subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$. But we cannot explicitly give one. Or more exactly, we cannot give an explicit set of which we can prove that its cardinality is $\aleph_1$. Of course since it is consistent that $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$, just $\mathbb R$ itself *might* be such an example. But we cannot prove or disprove it.

Note that my first paragraph is independent of the axiom of choice. However, the second paragraph isn't, as without the axiom of choice it is consistent that $|\mathbb R|\ngeq\aleph_1$.

Comment: Can't we well order the cardinals without AC? Cause the rationals have a clear injection on the reals.

Comment: @victormd: No, without AC we can't well-order all cardinals. It is true that $|\mathbb R|\gt \aleph_0$, as shown by the inclusion of the rationals (or, more directly, the natural numbers, which are the very definition of $\aleph_0$). But without AC, $|X|>\aleph_0$ does *not* imply $|X|\ge\aleph_1$.

Comment: Actually how is aleph one defined without AC then? Cause i always think of it as the smaller cardinal greater than aleph one, which wouldn't exist.

Comment: @victormd: Yes, $\aleph_1$ exists. It is the cardinality of the set of all well-orders of cardinality $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @celtschk: I think that without AC you have to be careful about what “cardinals” means. One can certainly define the cardinals by letting them be the alephs without AC (the alephs being the ordinals that cannot be bijected with any strictly smaller ordinal), but of course then the problem is that not every set is necessarily bijectable with a cardinal. But with that definition, the cardinals are trivially well-ordered, since they form a subclass of the ordinals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Even if you do so (and I'm not sure it's a reasonable thing to do), the cardinality of two sets can be compared even if you can't assign a cardinal to them. So even if that definition would cause a well-ordering of the so-defined cardinals, it would still not cause a well-ordering of cardinalities.

Comment: @celtschk: I think we are talking at cross purposes, or at least inexactly as to what exactly is being meant here. For one thing, the statement that given any two sets there is either an injection from one to the other or an injection from the other to the one is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice, and that is a statement that I would interpret as “the cardinality of two sets can be compared”. So I think this is really confusion because “cardinality” is unclear in the absence of Choice.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: When I said "the cardinality of two sets can be compared" I meant that there's a *partial* order that can be defined for all sets. That is, while without AC there certainly are sets where neither has an injection into the other, the question "is there an injection from this set to that set" is well-defined for each pair of sets, and indeed, for any set, there's another set that has an injection into it. The cardinality of Dedekind-finite sets is *unrelated* to the cardinality of the natural numbers, but they are not *uncomparable*, their comparision gives their unrelatedness.

Comment: In contrast, if you restrict the concept of “cardinality” to well-orderable sets, even the question whether a non-well-orderable set has a larger cardinality than some other set would lack any meaning.

Comment: @celtschk: as I suspected, this arises out of the problem of figuring out what “cardinality” means when you don’t have AC. To me, when you say “can be compared”, it implies that the order is *total*, not merely partial (as the defining characteristic of a total order vs a partial order is that you *can* compare any two elements). In any case, we are both aware that these notions become difficult and problematical in the absence of AC, and that careful definitions are needed in that case, and we can leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

Under $ZFC$ every set is equinumerous with some cardinal and can be well ordered, so you can just well order it and take the first $\kappa$ items for a subset of size $\kappa$.

It is consistent with $ZFC$ that the reals are of size $\aleph_1$, in which case any subset larger than $\aleph_0$ has size $\aleph_1$.  If the reals are larger than $\aleph_1$ they have a (many) subset(s) of size $\aleph_1$ but we cannot display one.  If we could and we could show it was smaller than the reals we would know the reals were at least $\aleph_2$.